# Use Expect to Fill In a Multiline Prompt

Tags: linux, forms, unix, expect, cat

I am trying to use Expect to autocomplete some prompts. One of the prompts, asks the user to enter some text and then press CTR-D to save the text or CTR-C to cancel. I do not know for sure, but I assume the program that I am trying to autocomplete is using cat to write to a file (like cat > file.txt).

Expect does not seem to be able to send text to this multiline prompt. When I execute, the line "Enter task description (^D to end text entry, ^C to abort): " appears and then it just hangs until it times out. Does anyone know how to do this using Expect?

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

spawn tasks create

expect "Task assigned to (default=you): "
send "name\r"

expect "Enter a title: "
send "This is a test\r"

expect "Priority (default=wishlist): "
send "high\r"

expect "Comma-separated list of subscribers (default=None): "
send "None\r"

expect "Comma-separated list of task tags (default=None): "
send "None\r"

 expect "Enter task description (^D to end text entry, ^C to abort): "
 send "Description\r"
 send /004
```

Result:

```
[name@xxxx.xxx ~/createtasks] ./innerscript.exp
spawn tasks create
Task assigned to (default=you): name
Enter a title: This is a test
Priority (default=wishlist): high
Comma-separated list of subscribers (default=None): None
Comma-separated list of task tags (default=None): None
Enter task description (^D to end text entry, ^C to abort):
[name@xxxx.xxx ~/createtasks]
```

It seems like this should be simple... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the script, add:

```
set timeout -1    ;# wait for as long as necessary
expect eof        ;# for the spawned task to end.
```